# Default value from a model to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model-Activity who contains a collection of another model: Exigence. When I show the Activity details, including its Exigences list, I need to add another exigence to this list.The problem is that I don't know how to add the FK ActivityId automatically to my new object Exigence. When creating in my DB I have IdActivity null.

My models:

```
public partial class Activity
{
    public Activity()
    {
        this.EXIGENCE = new HashSet<Exigence>();
    }

    public string IdActivity { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateService { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; 
    public virtual ICollection<Exigence> REE_EXIGENCE { get; set; }
}

public partial class Exigence
{
    public string IdExigence { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BeginingDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FinishDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string IdActivite { get; set; }
    public virtual Activite REE_ACTIVITE { get; set; }

}
```

The function who creates the exigence:

```
 public void AddExigence(Exigence exigence)
    {
        exigence = new Exigence
        {
            IdExigence = InsertNewIdExigence(exigence),
            BeginingDate = DateTime.Today,
            FinishDate = DateTime.Today,
            Description = exigence.Description,
            IdActivite = exigence.IdActivite
        };

        _context.EXIGENCE.Add(exigence);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateExigence(Exigence exigence)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _serviceExigence.AjouterExigence(exigence);
            return RedirectToAction("ShowExigence", new { id = exigence.IdExigence});
        }

        Activity act = new Activity();
        ViewBag.IdActivity = _serviceActivity.FindIdActivity(act.IdActivite);
        return View(exigence);
    }
```

Comment: You need to send activity id too. Just put it in the data you post.